# Close pipe even if subprocesses of first command is still running in background

Tags: bash, pipe, sh, background-process

Suppose I have `test.sh` as below. The intent is to run some background task(s) by this script, that continuously updates some file. If the background task is terminated for some reason, it should be started again.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f pidfile ] && kill -0 $(cat pidfile); then
    cat somewhere
    exit
fi

while true; do
    echo "something" >> somewhere
    sleep 1
done &
echo $! > pidfile
```

and want to call it like `./test.sh | otherprogram`, e. g. `./test.sh | cat`.

The pipe is not being closed as the background process still exists and might produce some output. How can I tell the pipe to close at the end of `test.sh`? Is there a better way than checking for existence of `pidfile` before calling the pipe command?

As a variant I tried using `#!/bin/bash` and `disown` at the end of `test.sh`, but it is still waiting for the pipe to be closed.

---

What I actually try to achieve: I have a "status" script which collects the output of various scripts (`uptime`, `free`, `date`, `get-xy-from-dbus`, etc.), similar to this `test.sh` here. The output of the script is passed to my window manager, which displays it. It's also used in my GNU screen bottom line.

Since some of the scripts that are used might take some time to create output, I want to detach them from output collection. So I put them in a `while true; do script; sleep 1; done` loop, which is started if it is not running yet.

The problem here is now that I don't know how to tell the calling script to "really" detach the daemon process.

Comment: Can you let us know, what is the TERMINATING condition for the script? I mean, when the 'waiting' process is expected to end?

Comment: The script should terminate after the end is reached. It terminates correctly if its output is not piped, i. e. just calling `./test.sh`.

Comment: I think I understood your question. I will try to find answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this serves your purpose:
(I am assuming that you are not interested in any stderr of commands in while loop. You would adjust the code, if you are. :-) )

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f pidfile ] && kill -0 $(cat pidfile); then
    cat somewhere
    exit
fi

while true; do
    echo "something" >> somewhere
    sleep 1
done >/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $! > pidfile
```

Comment: That does it! `>/dev/null` is the solving part. The subshell (braces around while) is not needed, but `&` then has to be placed after `2>&1`. Then the last line also works (which it does not with this code, since the outer shell does not know the PID of the background process).

Comment: I've edited it (awaiting peer review), in case someone else comes across this. I can award you the bounty in one hour. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to explicitly close a file descriptor, like for example 1 which is standard output, you can do it with:

```
exec 1<&-
```

This is valid for POSIX shells, see: [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/exec.html)

Comment: It is ment to run all the time and be started if it is not running, so killing the subprocess or waiting unfortunately won't help.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for not understanding you're question. I don't think I fully understood it yet, but I think I'm starting to. I edited it into another answer. I'm not 100% sure this is what you want, but hopefully it helps =)

Comment: Thank you for giving the hint with exec. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I tried putting `exec 1<&-` at the end of the script, which as far as I understood it should have closed the stdout fd. But still, running the script as `./test.sh | cat`, it does not return. Adding `exec 2<&-` to close stderr as well didn't do it either.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the while loop in an explicit subshell and run the subshell in the background it will give the desired behaviour.

```
(while true; do
    echo "something" >> somewhere
    sleep 1
done)&
```

Comment: please explain. You're talking bash? Good luck to all.

Comment: Sorry, running it like `./test.sh | cat` still does not return but wait forever.

Comment: Bad idea. This runs in the background ad infinitum. If this code is in the A.sh script, and if it is started by the B.sh script, then the B.sh script process will also be active, without the exit(0) of the B.sh script.
You should, upon starting A.sh, take the PPID and kill it so it doesn't stay active.